How to Edit or Update contact in react-native-contacts?
I am using react-native-contacts to get a contact list, delete a contact from the list, and add a contact to the list in react-native. So far I have achieved all three functionalities but to edit contact details let's say its name or number using Contacts.updateContact() is not working.
You can see the below code to see what I am doing -
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Image, TextInput, TouchableHighlight, PermissionsAndroid } from 'react-native';
import Contacts from 'react-native-contacts';

const EditContactScreen = ({ route, navigation }) => {
    const { data } = route.params;
    const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState(data.givenName);
    const [lastName, setLastName] = useState(data.familyName);
    const [number, setNumber] = useState(data.phoneNumbers[0].number);
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');

    console.log('data>>>', JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));

    const editContact = () => {
        PermissionsAndroid.request(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_CONTACTS, {
            title: 'Contacts',
            message: 'This app would like to view your contacts.',
            buttonPositive: 'Please accept bare mortal',
        })
            .then((res) => {
                console.log('Permission: ', res);
                if (res === 'granted') {
                    let updatedContact = {
                        recordID: data.recordID,
                        emailAddresses: [{
                            label: 'work',
                            email: email,
                        }],
                        phoneNumbers: [{
                            label: 'mobile',
                            number: number,
                        }],
                        familyName: lastName,
                        givenName: firstName,
                    };

                    Contacts.updateContact(updatedContact).then(() => {
                        console.log('Contact updated successfully');
                        navigation.goBack();
                    }).catch(error => {
                        console.log('Error updating contact:', error);
                    });
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error('Permission error: ', error);
            });
    };

    const onSubmit = () => {
        editContact();
    };

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                placeholder="First Name"
                defaultValue={firstName}
                onChangeText={text => setFirstName(text)}
                placeholderTextColor={'#555'}
                cursorColor={'#555'}
            />
            <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                placeholder="Last Name"
                defaultValue={lastName}
                onChangeText={text => setLastName(text)}
                placeholderTextColor={'#555'}
                cursorColor={'#555'}
            />
            <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                placeholder="Phone Number"
                defaultValue={number}
                onChangeText={text => setNumber(text)}
                placeholderTextColor={'#555'}
                keyboardType="numeric"
                cursorColor={'#555'}
            />
                <TouchableHighlight
                    style={[styles.button]}
                    onPress={onSubmit}
                >
                    <Text style={styles.btnText}>Save Contact</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
    );
};
export default EditContactScreen;

I am getting data through route.params from ContactDetail Screen and from that passing recordId to the updatedContact, now whenever I call for editContact() after editing it is giving me error as
Error updating contact: [Error: Invalid recordId or rawContactId]

Even Though as you can see I am passing the recordId correctly but still it is giving me error so what should I do?
